# "A deep bronzing effect to her skin"

Tags: prepositions

Why is the preposition **to** used here in [this sentence](https://www.billboard.com/articles/news/8454346/gigi-hadid-apology-vogue-italia-blackface-cover)? Does it go with **effect** or **skin**? I thought it's more common to say "*effect on something*" and "*on the skin*."

> The controversial image, taken by star photographer Steven Klien, shows Hadid with such a deep bronzing effect **to** her skin that many took it to be a racist overture.

Comment: It's awkward phrasing. Could perhaps be *slightly* improved with *deep bronzing effect **on** her skin*, but it's really just a mess anyway.

Comment: Why there is no article before **star**? Surely, neither _photographer_, nor _Steven Klien_ is a mass noun. Should it not be **the star photographer Steven Klien**?

Comment: @Mv Log: It's perfectly natural to delete the article in such contexts (in *particular*, "popular journalism / gossip column" contexts as per the example). Consider [(somebody worked) with star comedian (somebody else).](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+star+comedian%22) A bit "tabloid journalese", maybe. But not exactly unknown in natural colloquial speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I think the author meant some [Photoshop effect](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=22&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjN0qv1iPLcAhVJG5oKHeUfD7wQFjAVegQICBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.photoshopessentials.com%2Fphoto-effects%2F&usg=AOvVaw2ZfEwwNpr0-d_qQQWQKqxu) (applied) to her skin.

Comment: @Mv Log: I know. That's what makes it "awkward". Assuming you didn't *start* with the concept of photographic manipulation (at the levels of tweaking colour reproduction, rather than just "shot choice / composition" as we normally think of with "star photographers"). But when I got to the syntactically "awkward" bit I was thinking in terms of *what Hadid looked like* (like she's got something ***on*** her skin), rather than thinking about *what might have been done **to** the digital image file*.

Comment: You often see 'to' used when discussing actions having physical effects on people's bodies, e.g. in police or medical reports - bruising to the face, cuts to the arms, lacerations to the hand, etc. Both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: "Avon GLOW-Bronzing Powder This product is great for creating an illusion of bronzing to the skin. " --- also --- "After that [cosmetic laser treatment], patients experience some bronzing to the skin followed by peeling."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked a similar question the other day. **to** can express an attribute relationship. The object of preposition **to** is that which has the attribute.

> There is a trick to it.
>
> There was a pleasant lilt to her voice.
>
> There's a limit to what he will put up with.

Now, **bronzing effect** is semantically not well suited to being cast as an *attribute*, but we can understand it here to be a synonym for **bronze tone** or **bronze color**.

*There was such a deep bronze tone to her skin—the result of photographic filters—that many took the effect to be a racist overture.*

Comment: Looking at this answer and your _part-to-whole_ explanation in your other answer together does make things clearer for me! I guess what I am still not sure about is when/if other prepositions such as _in_, _on_, _of_ can also be used. For example, is "There was a pleasant lilt **in** her voice" or "There was not a trace of accent **in** his voice" wrong? Less common? Equally idiomatic?

Comment: Equally idiomatic to be sure.  We'd need data for frequency, and we'd also have to take demographics into account.  **to** may be used  more  often by boomers than by millenials.

Comment: And by whatever the counterpart generations are called in the UK.